# Alternative to the Wilcoxon test when the distribution isn't continuous?

Tags: r, nonparametric, sign-test, wilcoxon-signed-rank

One of the assumptions for using the Wilcoxon sign-rank test is that the underlying distribution is continuous ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilcoxon_signed-rank_test#Assumptions).)

However, there are cases (for example, when analyzing Likert scale data) where this assumption might not necessarily hold.  In such cases, what test can you use? And how would you do it with R?

(My only bet here is to use a randomization test on the median - which I imagine can be easily done using the boot package.)

Comment: Likert scale is actually a good example of an underlying continuous variable that is collected in discrete fashion.

Comment: @Aniko Right, but the problem is that we're not sure how well the original interval scale fits into the discretized one, unless making strong assumptions. Optimal scaling might be an option there.

Comment: @chl That's why you are using Wilcoxon's test instead of a t-test. Wilcoxon's test does not assume equally spaced intervals, etc, so scaling is not an issue.

Comment: @Aniko I agree with you. My comment was not a critic, and reference to optimal scaling was mainly for the case where the assumption of an *a priori* continuous scale of measurement is not tenable--because in practice, we often rely on Likert items without making strong assumption on the underlying construct; I also agree for Mann-Whitney test with ordinal variables.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found that the Wilcoxon statistic is still fine for this purpose and that small simulations do a good job of estimating the size and the power of the test.  I suspect this is more powerful than just comparing the two medians.  The main concern is lack of power due to extensive numbers of ties, but that concern attaches to *any* solution you can conceive of: there's no way around it (except to design instruments that offer a wider range of responses!).

To perform the simulation, concatenate the two data arrays (of lengths $n$ and $m$) into a single array (of length $n+m$).  In each iteration randomly permute the elements of the array and break the result into the first $n$ and last $m$ elements.

Comment: (+1) Agree, i think the assumption of a continuous distribution may affect the standard way of calculating p-values, but simulation as suggested by whuber gets around that (i'd call this a permutation test).

Comment: @onestop That is correct.  Indeed, the Wilcoxon test *is* a permutation test.  All we're discussing is how to compute (or estimate) the distribution of the test statistic.  The distribution can be computed exactly using combinatorial techniques; it can be estimated through simulation; and it can be approximated, usually with a Normal approximation when the amount of data is large enough (m+n of 10 or greater is usually good enough) and the data can be thought of as realizations of a continuous RV.

Comment: You're right of course @whuber, i meant "i'd call that a *Monte-Carlo* permutation test*". (Sorry was in too much of a hurry for no good reason really)

Comment: @onestop I didn't mean to sound critical.  I was agreeing with you and felt your meaning was clear.

Comment: So maybe I'm missing something - is the assumption of continuous distribution only needed for the approximation of the normal distribution of the statistic?

Comment: @Tal I believe that is the case.  In fact, the Wilcoxon (Mann-Whitney) rank sum test is actually required in some US state regulations due to its ability to handle certain kinds of non-continuous distributions resulting from data censoring: http://www.pabulletin.com/secure/data/vol27/27-33/1340c.html

Comment: @Tal and @whuber: I was puzzled by the implication (and then by its apparent acceptance) that the test statistic for the Wilcoxon(or M-W) was normally distributed.

Comment: @DWin For a continuous underlying distribution and sufficient sample sizes it is *approximately* normally distributed.  The exact distribution, however, is not normal and departs appreciably from normality when there are less than 10 values (in both datasets combined).  Tables of the distribution have been published to cover those small-data cases, but it is readily computed nowadays by brute force.  (E.g., with 10 values it takes little time to generate all the possible combinations.)