# Test for comparing highly skewed charge data

Tags: r, bootstrap, skewness, wilcoxon-signed-rank, permutation-test

I'm looking into comparing charge/cost (economics) data among paired samples (i.e pre vs post). The sample size is about ~150 paired samples, where charge/cost is highly skewed with a long tail.

I'm concerned about using a paired t-test as it violates the assumption of normality, and I've been looking into using the coin package in r for its implementation of the fisher-pitman permutation test. Upon doing some research, I've also read about possibly doing a bootstrapped hypothesis test? Would a wilcoxon signed rank test be appropriate in this case? What would be most appropriate in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

Wilcoxon is indicated for what you describe.

[Edit] as @greenparker said this needs some explaining.

t-test assumes equal standard deviation and that a fitted normal describes the data.

If those assumptions are not suitable, or at least, if a plot shows that can be a very bad assumption, then use a method that does not make the assumptions or transform the data (e.g. applying logs)

Wilcoxon is the distribution-free version of t-test for paired data.

Comment: According to Wikipedia in German and in Catalan, Wilcoxon test assumes symmetrical distribution. Answers to http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14434/appropriateness-of-wilcoxon-signed-rank-test give somehow conflicting statements about it. Therefore, is skewness a problem for Wilcoxon text? If it were, it would be less suitable for this question.

Comment: I agree with commenting and discussing details but it seems that Wikipedia is not a right source. My stats professor edited Wikipedia adding intentional errors to make us thinking about what can be a "correct" or a "bad" solution. 
Please check this from Northwestern University
http://www.basic.northwestern.edu/statguidefiles/srank_paired_ass_viol.html

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to compare the means, the t-test can be used since it is robust to departures of normality. See my previous answer: [Hypothesis testing options on non-normal populations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226282/hypothesis-testing-options-on-non-normal-populations/226296#226296)

Alternatively, you can compare them using nonparametric approaches such as the one proposed [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1209.1902), where the authors calculate $P(X<Y)$ for paired observations in order to assess discrepancies between $X$ and $Y$. Alternative parametric approaches using skewed dependent distributions have also been studied [here](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ba/1362406651)